# Linux cp command to copy a folder to current directory

Tags: cp

I am wondering if there is an identical command for copying a folder to current directory like it did using the old MS-DOS. Let's say my current directory location is:

```
/var/www/
```

I have folders and files at:

```
/home/hope/subfolder/docs/
/home/hope/subfolder/images/
/home/hope/subfolder/.config
/home/hope/subfolder/readme.txt
```

I know that the following command:

```
cp -rT /home/hope/subfolder .
```

will copy all the files (even dot hidden files) and folders within the "subfolder" folder to the current directory, so the result will be:

```
/var/www/docs/
/var/www/images/
/var/www/.config
/var/www/readme.txt
```

Looks like the command to that to copy the source folder to the current location is:

```
cp -rT /home/hope/subfolder ./subfolder
```

although this is fine, I find it that sometimes I will make mistakes for complicated folder names for the destination, so is there a way to use a command like:

```
cp -rT /home/hope/subfolder .
```

or even like this

```
cp -rT /home/hope/subfolder /var/www/.
```

to have the following result:

```
/var/www/subfolder/docs/
/var/www/subfolder/images/
/var/www/subfolder/.config
/var/www/subfolder/readme.txt
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried cp -r /home/hope/subfolder /var/www/

Comment: Just omit the `-T` parameter and it will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just omit the -T parameter, as that's what prevents the command from working properly:

```
cp -r /home/hope/subfolder .
```

The -T parameter treats the target argument as a file, so no copying will be performed at all if that is actually a directory.

A friendly reminder: virtually all Unix commands have a *--help* command line argument that is worth trying out in case of a trouble :)

Comment: I see :) Will that also allow copying hidden files inside the "subfolder"? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Reading man pages is like reading a mathematics paper. Not fun.

Answer (score 4):

For me the main barrier was the /home part. I needed to copy files from a folder in my home that started with the letter 'a' to my current folder, which was not home. So I used:

```
cp home/tmp/a* ./
```

the first line worked for me. While I was trying commands like:

```
cp ~/home/tmp/a* ./
```

but this didn't work.